# Which has higher precedence in C -multiplication or division?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
int w=2*3/2;             //1
int x=5%2*3/2;           //2
printf("%d  %d",w,x);
return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT
3   1

In (1); it is giving higher precedence to multiplication than division while in (2) its vice versa. Why so?

Comment: whichever is on the left of the other...

Comment: What if there is a question where Associativity is L to R for some and R to L for others?

Comment: Not every operator has the same associativity, but different operators *with the same priority* have the same associativity, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They have the same precedence and are always executed left to right.

```
2*3/2 = (2*3)/2 => 3
            6/2 => 3
```

and

```
5%2*3/2 = ((5%2)*3)/2 => 1
              (1*3)/2 => 1
                  3/2 => 1 (integer gets truncated)
```

Answer (score 2):

Left to the right counts in that case.
But anyway!
In some of the academic literature, implied multiplication is interpreted as having higher precedence than division. So there is a different way this can be seen.
And that's also the reason why mathematicians or physicians try to avoid this kind of notation in the first place and write a fraction instead.

Comment: i think by physician, you mean physicist. and by fraction you mean decimal.

Comment: Yeah, isn't "physician" basically another word for "medical doctor"? :-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mixed_division_and_multiplication

Answer (score 1):

My friend multiplication and division have same precedence.But in this code that you had written both came together in an expression So when two operators came together in an expression then we check "Associativity" here it is "left to right" So in

```
1)it will first solve multiplication than division.left to right
```

an in

```
2)it will first solve % then * than /.left to right
```

For more information plz read carefully Associativity and precedence of operators in C you can easily find this on internet.

Comment: What if there is a question where Associativity is L to R for some and R to L for others?

Comment: First of all it is pre-defined and generally most of arithmetic operators have associativity L to R.

Comment: For increment and decrement operator it is R to L.. and they are widely used, so that's why i was asking.

Comment: and also they have more precedence than arithmetic operators so they will be evaluated first in this case.